# How do you "season" your oven racks?

Tags: oven

After running the self-cleaning cycle on my oven, the racks are now kind of bare and don't slide in and out easily. Is there a way to "season" them like you would cast-iron?

Answer (score 4):

The racks are probably chromed, so you should not have to season them.

I'd remove them from the oven and give them a good wipe with clear water to remove and residues that the self-cleaning cycle might put on them (especially if you you cleaning products).

And also wipe clean the channels where the racks slide in the oven (on each side)